# Creating a Cocoa radio button programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, radio-button

I need to make a Cocoa radio button programmatically, can anyone explain how this might be done or how to do this well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a sample code for creating radio buttons programmatically:

```
//create the radio button prototype
NSButtonCell *proto = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
[proto setTitle:@"Options"];
[proto setButtonType: NSRadioButton];

//define the matrix size where you'll put the radio buttons
NSRect matrixRect = NSMakeRect(20.0,20.0,125.0,125.0);

//define the matrix specifying that it will contain radio buttons of
//prototype "proto" defined above, and that it will have 3 radio buttons 
//arranged on 1 column
NSMatrix *matrix = [[NSMatrix alloc] initWithRect: matrixRect
                                     mode: NSRadioModeMatrix
                                     prototype: (NSCell *)proto
                                     numberOfRows:3 numberOfColumns:1];

//this assumes that you connected the window object to an outlet
[[windowOutlet contentView] addSubview: matrix];

//set the radio buttons' titles by getting references to the matrix's cells
NSArray *cells = [matrix cells];
[[cells objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Option 1"];
[[cells objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"Option 2"];
[[cells objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"Option 3"];

[proto release];
[matrix release];
```

Have fun! Yes, this is taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Concepts/RadioButtons.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/20000252), but i added some personal comments to explain the process.

Comment: Very nice and thank you. Why isn't this code in the Matrix Programming Guide?

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [here:](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2004/9/28/118417)

> Radio buttons are in fact a matrix if button cells.  The exclusive
>   selectivity is a property of the matrix.
>
> To programmatically create a matrix of button cells you do exactly the same
>   operations programmatically that IB does as the result of your input.  e.g.
>   Create an NSMatrix instance, set its cell prototype to an NSButtonCell, set
>   that attributes of the matrix via its public methods (the same ones IB
>   uses), and set the attributes of the prototype button cell and or all of the
>   contained button cells.

Also see [this link](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSButton) for more sample code on how to make an NSMatrix programatically.

Answer (score 2):

[The NSButton Class reference is here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbutton)

Button programming topics, specifically Radio Button (with sample code)
[can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Concepts/RadioButtons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000252)