# NSMatrix undeclared

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I tried creating Radio Buttons using this example

[Creating a Cocoa radio button programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456936/creating-a-cocoa-radio-button-programatically)

I copy and pasted the code inside my loadView method, when I run build and compile I get NSMatrix undeclared.

Please advise, I have UIKit.h included in my .h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSMatrix isn't available in UIKit (i.e. on iOS). you can look at UISegmentedControl for similar behaviour on iOS.